# What is the best approach to identify the pressed button if the button is coming from a list in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I have a list of item and I am displaying those items by using *ngFor. And I have a button with a function, on each iterated independent item. 
Code is below.

```
 <ul *ngFor="let data of datas">

//                 . . .

                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-sm"
                  (click)="showDetail(**parameter**)"
                  >  show
                </button>
//                 . . .
```

This is my show function. I have no idea what to pass in this **parameter**.

```
increment(**parameter**) {
    console.log(this.data[**parameter**]['price']);
  }
```

I want to display the price of the particular selected item. My data list is below.

```
[
      { id: "1111", guest: "abc", price: 20 },
      { id: "222", guest: "xyz", price: 30 }    ]
```

Comment: just pass `data` as parameter, and then you have it inside `data.price` in component. Or then pass `data.price` as parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send `data` as parameter

```
<ul *ngFor="let data of datas">
...
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-sm" (click)="showDetail(data)">  
      show
   </button>
...
</ul>


increment(data) {
  console.log(data.price);
}
```

Or you can send `index`

```
<ul *ngFor="let data of datas; let i = index">
...
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-sm" (click)="showDetail(i)">  
      show
   </button>
...
</ul>


increment(index) {
  console.log(this.data[index]['price']);
}
```